# contenteditable div placeholder color in Windows high contrast mode

Tags: html, css

I have a contenteditable div for users to input text.
There is a placeholder for that div, which works fine for regular mode.
The color doesn't looks right in high contrast mode. I want to make sure the placeholder stands out in Windows high contrast mode.
[image: This is in regular mode.]

In IE, the default high contrast placeholder color is "green" for input, or other controls. Since the placeholder is not a default attribute tag for div, the "green" color is not automatically picked up.
[image: This is in high contrast]

```
<div id="somediv" contenteditable="true" placeholder="I am a placeholder"></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Payson/3L3r1w8m/

We care about poor vision customers too. This is important to our potential customers. Kindly please help. I couldn't find enough resources for this info.

Answer (score 1):

I fount a way

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) 
{
    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before
    {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      font-style: italic;
      color: #00FF00;
    }
}
```

However, it supports IE only, not firefox. Chrome has it's only plugin to turn on high contrast mode. Waiting answers for firefox.