# How to change HTML placeholder color under Windows high contrast mode?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, high-contrast

Suppose I have the following HTML placeholder:

```
<input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" placeholder="enter here" />
```

I was able to change its color to blue using the CSS stylesheet:

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #428bca;
}
```

However, if I turn on high contrast mode in Windows, the placeholder color becomes grey (I think that's the default color). How can I change the placeholder color under high contrast mode?

I've made two attempts so far, but none of them ended up working.

Attempt 1 (copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213741/contenteditable-div-placeholder-color-in-windows-high-contrast-mode)):

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
        content: attr(placeholder);
        font-style: italic;
        color: #00FF00;
    }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #428bca;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!